# "Ambiguous call to overloaded function"

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

I have a structure like this, with struct Baz inheriting from 2 different structs, Foo and Bar.

I have 2 methods called the same thing, one with a parameter of Foo and one with a parameter of Baz.

```
struct Foo
{
};

struct Bar
{
};

struct Baz : Foo, Bar
{
    virtual void something(const Foo& foo)
    {
    };

    virtual void something(const Bar& bar)
    {
    };
};
```

I call it like this

```
Baz baz;
baz.something(baz);
```

And understandably I have an issue with my code knowing which function I am calling if I pass it an instance of Baz. I get “Ambiguous call to overloaded function”.

I know I can cast my Baz to Foo or Bar to resolve the issue...

```
Baz baz;
baz.something((Bar)baz);
```

...but is there another way of dealing with this design issue?

I want to call the Foo method ONLY if the object being passed is not of type Bar.

edit:

*If this was C# (which it isn't) I could probably solve this using a template where clause.*

Comment: Well, WHAT exactly do you want the compiler to do in this case? (And why on this earth are you doing this?) `Baz` is possible to convert to both `Foo` and `Bar`. You will need to tell the compiler which you want in some way - I guess you could do an explicit conversion for `Baz` to `Foo` that is deleted in C++11, which means that it's not available. Or implement a `something` for `Baz` that calls the `Bar` version... Or simply implement the `DoSomething` virtual function for each class, including `Baz` that gets called by `something`.

Comment: Why do you have to give same name to these methods? You can avoid ambiguity by using different names to them. I cannot understand the necessity to make this strange code.

Comment: Please tell me you don't mean something as [**horrible as this**](http://ideone.com/HeFsDS).

Comment: @Beakie the aroma of a bad-design is just-plain putrid if something like that works.

Comment: Ok, I will go have a restructure. I have to agree. Think I will just add an instance of Foo in Bar and that way it will use the Bar function unless foo.Bar is passed. Better?

Comment: @WhozCraig I can't really see why. Substitute `PrintableAsRtf` for `Bar`, `PrintableAsTxt` for `Foo` and `printAsPrettyAsPossible()` for `something()`.

Comment: @Beakie how you do it is up to you (obviously). *Clarity* should play at least some role in that adventure. If this is really your only option so be it, but I shudder to think that it is. Maybe gel another day on it. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, note that the cast you've used would create a temporary object. You probably meant this:

```
baz.something(static_cast<Bar&>(baz));
```

And to answer your question, it should be possible to use SFINAE for this:

```
struct Baz : Foo, Bar
{
  virtual void something(const Bar &bar)
  { /* ... */ }

  template <
    class T,
    class = typename std::enable_if<
      std::is_convertible<const T&, const Foo&>::value &&
      !std::is_convertible<const T&, const Bar&>::value
    >::type
  >
  void something (const T &foo)
  { something_impl(static_cast<const Foo&>(foo)); }

private:
  virtual void something_impl(const Foo &foo)
  { /* ... */ }
};
```

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/EVOHAH)